# Could we change things so that questions marked as community wiki will not show up in unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, unanswered-questions

Could we change things so that questions marked as community wiki will not show up in unanswered questions?
It's somewhat annoying on ServerFault that the top two questions under "unanswered" are both community wiki, including the FAQ, which really doesn't need an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're CW, just add an answer to them.  It's not like you have to worry about a rep hit.  It's a kludge, but yet so very fitting in this field.

Rich B informs me that the answers still require an upvotes in order to take it off the unanswered page.  Therefore, I retract that answer and instead offer this:

There might be some reasons for this, but I'm not too certain what they are.  If you're just looking to earn rep, it's easy enough to tell which questions are CW from the listing page.  Unless the page is completely clogged with CW questions, it strikes me as an extremely low-priority issue.

Comment: It may be low priority, but it's still annoying.